# Touch Table Web Apps

Tags: html, multi-touch

I'm building a touch table application, and I want to use HTML5 technology, in the interest of creating something that's cross-platform, moving away from Flash, as well as learning HTML5 technology in general.  There are some technologies I've found that would potentially work, like javascript's built-in touch events, or KineticJS, both of which run in a canvas tag.  Then there are frameworks targeting mobile platforms using HTML5 technology, like PhoneGap and Sencha Touch.

I was wondering if anyone had any technology recommendations for building touch table web applications.  I've worked with building touch table apps in Flash, but I'd like to explore alternative non-Flash technologies.  It seems there are some APIs out there, but I haven't found much support for rich touch gestures that would be suitable for a larger scale touch display like a touch table.  Javascript and KineticJS don't have built-in pinch-zoom or flick gestures, for example.  Most APIs are targeting mobile platforms (understandably so) which are obviously smaller scale screens.

Any leads would be a huge help!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is viewing this issue still, there are a few leads that I've found that might be of interest.

Hammer JS seems like a pretty neat Javascript library, although there seem to be a few weird issues with transformations in their pinch zoom sample.

http://www.contrejour.ie/, a popular iPad game, has been ported to the browser.  If you're running an attached touchscreen, the game will run in a browser.  Looks like these folks just straight up built their own multitouch system.

Intuilab made a blog post back in 2011 about "massive multitouch for the web." You can find it here: http://www.intuilab.com/company/press/intuilab-introduces-massive-multi-touch-for-the-web-browser/
Seems like an interesting technology.

Wish there was more open-source stuff going on, like hammer.js! If anyone else is viewing this still, please let me know if you've got any more leads.